Why SharePoint online is not saving my calculated column formula
I have created a calculated column of type Date/time with this formula:-
=IF([DueDateTime]="12:00 AM", [DueDate],
IF([DueDateTime]="1:00 AM", [DueDate] + 60/(24*60),
IF([DueDateTime]="2:00 AM", [DueDate] + 120/(24*60),
IF([DueDateTime]="3:00 AM", [DueDate] + 180/(24*60),
IF([DueDateTime]="4:00 AM", [DueDate] + 240/(24*60),
IF([DueDateTime]="5:00 AM", [DueDate] + 300/(24*60),
IF([DueDateTime]="6:00 AM", [DueDate] + 360/(24*60),
IF([DueDateTime]="7:00 AM", [DueDate] + 420/(24*60),
IF([DueDateTime]="8:00 AM", [DueDate] + 480/(24*60),
IF([DueDateTime]="9:00 AM", [DueDate] + 540/(24*60),
IF([DueDateTime]="10:00 AM", [DueDate] + 600/(24*60),
IF([DueDateTime]="11:00 AM", [DueDate] + 660/(24*60),
[DueDate]))))))))))))


but when I try to apply this formula to the site column I will get this message forever: -

and the formula will not get applied to the list column and hence to the list. any advice? i read that in SharePoint online we can only have 19 nested If statements inside calculated columns, but in my case i only have 12.. so why this is not working?

After my tests you have no problem with the formula.
Whether all SharePoint lists have the same problem? Check if the same issue occurs with other SharePoint site collections. This could be an update issue, try waiting a few days to see if it gets fixed.
